# Is there any reason not to combine my Roth conversion IRA with a Roth "non-conversion" IRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I have two smallish Roth IRA accounts that were established when I was much younger based on some summer jobs.  One was initiated as a Roth from the start. The other was a traditional, which was converted to Roth.  I'm thinking about consolidating them into one account for simplicity and to concentrate buying power, but I was told way back that there were "tax reasons" that I should keep them separate.

I'm thinking that the tax reasons (which I admit I never understood at the time and then just forgot completely as these accounts hung around) had to do with the 5-year rule mentioned in several places, such as this question [What is the "Taxable portion of a conversion" in a roth IRA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28099/what-is-the-taxable-portion-of-a-conversion-in-a-roth-ira).  It's way more than 5 years now since the conversion, so is there any *other* reason to continue keeping these account separate?

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason. The 5 year rule applies to the amounts, not accounts. At some point of time you couldn't roll over from IRA to 401(k) unless the IRA account was originated in a roll over from a previous 401(k), but that is not a relevant situation for you anyway.